# When an EC2 instance is stopped, are you charged for instance-related storage?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am considering launching a high memory cluster EC2 instance for very intermittent use, which includes 240 GB SSD storage *with* the instance.

Most of the time, this instance will be stopped.

I would like to know if I will be charged a monthly storage fee for the 240 GB SSD storage associated with the instance, even when the instance is stopped.

Comment: Apparently stack overflow did not think the question was off-topic at that forum ...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549035/do-you-get-charged-for-a-stopped-instance-on-ec2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data on those instance-store drives will not survive a stoppage. They'll be blank when you start the instance back up.

> If an instance reboots (intentionally or unintentionally), data in the instance store persists. However, data on instance store volumes is lost under the following circumstances:
>
> - Failure of an underlying drive
> - **Stopping an Amazon EBS-backed instance**
> - Terminating an instance

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Comment: I am perfectly happy with that.  I don't need the data stored.  However - I notice that the data will generally **persist** (it will only be wiped when there's a failure or termination, in my case).  I do not want it to persist.  However - from this reasoning - it now occurs to me that I *will* be charged assuming it *does* persist.

Comment: There's no storage charge for instance-store data, ever - it's part of the instance cost. It'll only persist if the stopped instance happens to start back up on the same spot on the same server - more likely on the larger instances. If it gets moved to a different host (likely if it's stopped for a while, or a smaller instance) the disks' data doesn't come with.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  However, if my instance is *not* EBS-backed (which I assume it is not if it is an *instance* store), then it seems that none of the three conditions will apply (if the drive does not fail, and if my instance is not terminated).  Am I correct that instance-based storage is not EBS-backed?

Comment: First, if you can stop the instance, it's not instance-backed. Instance-store-backed servers can only be terminated. EBS-backed instances also (except for micros) still have instance-store drives available for use.

Comment: That must be it, thanks.  http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ (under the section for `High Memory Cluster Eight Extra Large Instance` does *not* say "EBS-backed"; instead, it says `240 GB of SSD instance storage`.  Therefore, reading that official description of the instance type does not make it clear that this is EBS-backed storage.

Comment: You can pick when you set up the instance (by picking different AMIs) - any instance type except micros can be either EBS-backed or instance-backed. Instance-backed vs. EBS-backed just affects where the root volume is served from.

Comment: I now see that the `root device` is listed as `EBS` for this instance.  That, then, appears to be confirmation that this instance is ESB-backed.  Since the description for the instance type says `instance storage`, it is understandably unclear - because the phrase `instance storage` can easily be taken to mean `instance backed`, whereas apparently in this case it is actually `EBS-backed`.

Comment: Again, EBS-backed instances still have instance storage that comes with the instance (which you can choose to use, or choose to ignore). It's fairly well documented in the EC2 user guides.